# custom image to add to maps marker

Tags: android, image, google-maps

I' m new on android, and I want some help about this thing. I have an image  whose url is on my online server.

eg.

*my url image is: `http:/example.com/image.png` and it is stored into my server, **and i want this image added  into the blank part in the middle of** [this image](http://www.nasc.fr/wp-content/custom_marker.png).*
[image]

I've added the image,of the above link, on my marker inside the map, but I can't figure out how to add inside the blank part another image.
my code snippet is this:

```
marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(title).snippet(snippetText)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker)));
```

- `R.drawable.custom_marker` -> is the image in the link above.

any helps on how to do that? is there a way to retrieve the image from my web server and add this feature?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have already asked this and your question was closed. And like previously you have a single vote up by yourself or your friend..

Comment: @user3249477 if you come here to say only this, i don't need your help,Anyway if you know any suggestion( apart graphical software) i'll appreciate.

Comment: Why do you wan to add it programatically when you can just download those two images, add them together with graphical software and save it on your drawable folder?

Comment: because, i want to do that automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw an image on top of your drawable you first will need to get the image. For that you will need to use an AsyncTask, as networking operations are forbidden on the UI thread.

To draw the bitmap you received (from your server) on top of the existing drawable, you'll need to create a mutable bitmap from it.

Then finally you can draw on top of it and use the result as a basis for your marker.

Here's an example:

```
class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Get bitmap from server
        Bitmap overlay;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.quarktet.com/Icon-small.jpg");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return overlay;     }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // If received bitmap successfully, draw it on our drawable
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.custom_marker);
            Bitmap newMarker = marker.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newMarker);
            // Offset the drawing by 25x25
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, null);
            // Add the new marker to the map
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(position)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(snippetText)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(newMarker)));
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init your map here

    new ImageTask().execute();
}
```

Comment: i'd use some library for loading images, and just load the bitmap and on the bitmap loaded callback add the marker.